# Behavior of HTML component selector in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dom, angular-components

When we create a component in Angular we have the selector that we use to display this component when necessary. When the page is generated, this selector is displayed in the DOM as an html tag.

I would like to know how this element behaves in the DOM. Does it have any default style? Does it behave like some known HTML element? Can I add classes, styles or other attributes to this tag?

Comment: Yes. No. Maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

If you're using a tag selector, Angular generates a custom HTML5 tag to bind your component to.

If you're using standard view encapsulation you can style the component using the `:host` selector on a S/CSS file attached to your component via `styleUrls` or `styles`.

If not, you can always style the component via a tag selector as you would any other tag.